# Novice implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: beginner, ruby, tic-tac-toe

After reading a lot of tutorials, I was finally able to code my version of a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I would like to have some honest review of the code to see what I can do to better my coding.

```
 class  Game

 attr_reader :board , :marker

def initialize 
    @board  = Array.new(3," "){Array.new(3," ")}
    @marker = ["X", "O"]
    #array that will be use to track all player move 
    #and use to find if there's any empty space on the board 
    @track_move ||= []
end

def create_players
    # create both players 
    @names = []

    @player_1 = ask "Please enter the first player name: "
    @names.push(@player_1)

    @player_2 = ask "Please enter second player name: "
    @names.push(@player_2)

    space
    puts"welcome #{@player_1.upcase} and #{@player_2.upcase}"
    print_separator
    space

    puts "Randomizing who'll start..."
    sleep(1)
    space
    # assign player by calling the player_assigment function that will determine who will start first
    player_assigment
    space
end

def space
    puts"\n"
end

def ask(question, kind="string")
    print question + " "
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase
    answer = answer.to_i if kind == "number"
    return answer 
end

def print_separator(character="-")
    puts character * 49
end

def player_assigment
    # merge the names array and symbol array 
    # with the zip method and return a nested array with player and symbol.  
    @choice = @names.shuffle.zip(marker)
    # iterate over the choice nested array and 
    # print out each player and their assigned symbol
    @assign = @choice.to_h
    @assign.each do |player, symbol| 
     puts "#{player.upcase} symbol is #{symbol}" 
    end
end

def first
    # choose the first array in choice nested array and return the first player and symbol
    first = @choice.first
    @first_player = first.first
    @symbol = first.last
    @current = @first_player
end

def second
    # choose the second array in choice nested array and return the second player and symbol
    second = @choice.last
    @second_player = second.first
    @symbol = second.last
    @current = @second_player
end

def first_turn
    first
    puts "it's #{@first_player.upcase} with '#{@symbol}' turn"
    make_move
end

def next_turn
    second
    puts "#{@second_player.upcase} with '#{@symbol}' turn"
    make_move
end

def invalid
    puts"Invalid move"
    space
end

def make_move
    @move = ask("Where to:","number")
    space
    mapping(@move,@symbol)
end

def track_move(move)
    # each move will be assigned an integer value that 
    # will be used to determine if there's no more move left.
    if @current 
       @track_move.push(move)
    end
end

def process_move(move)
    print_board
    track_move(move)
    if move_left?
       end_print
       replay
    end
    check_win?
end

def mapping(move, symbol)
     case move
        when 0
            if board[0][0]=="X" || @board[0][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[0][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 1
            if board[0][1]=="X" || board[0][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
              board[0][1] = symbol
              process_move(@move)
            end

        when 2
            if board[0][2]=="X" || board[0][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[0][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 3
            if board[1][0]=="X" || board[1][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 4
            if board[1][1]=="X" || board[1][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][1] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 5
            if board[1][2]=="X" || board[1][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 6
            if board[2][0]=="X" || board[2][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 7
            if board[2][1]=="X" || board[2][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][1] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 8
            if board[2][2]=="X" || board[2][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        else 
               invalid
               make_move
    end
end

def end_print
    print_separator
    puts "Game over. ".upcase 
    puts "No more moves left. "
    print_separator
    space
end


def winner(player)
    print_separator
    puts"#{player.upcase} wins!! TICTACTOE"
    puts "Game over. ".upcase
    print_separator
    space
    replay
end

def replay      
    print "Do you want to play again?(y/n)"
    space
    ans = gets.chomp
    if ans == "y"
    Game.start
    else
        exit
    end
end

def move_left?
    sum  = @track_move.inject{|r, s| r + s}
    if sum == 36
       return true
    end
end

def check_win?
    player = @current
    symbol = @symbol
    if board[0][0] == symbol && 
       board[0][1] == symbol &&
       board[0][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[1][0] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[1][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[2][0] == symbol && 
       board[2][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[0][1] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][1] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[0][2] == symbol && 
       board[1][2] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player) 

    elsif
       board[0][2] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][0] == symbol
       winner(player) 

    elsif
       board[0][0] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    end
     return false
end

# display board in a matrix format 
def print_board
    board.each_slice(1) { |a| p a }
    space
end


def instructions
    print_separator
    puts "Instructions :Enter your first move by entering a number 1-9" 
    puts "corresponding to the grid on the bottom and press enter"
    print_separator
    space
    puts "0 | 1 | 2 ",             
         "----------",              
         "3 | 4 | 5 ",             
         "----------",            
         "6 | 7 | 8 " 
    space

end

def players_turn
    loop do
        first_turn
        next_turn
    end
end

def self.start
    puts"------------------------------------------------"
    puts"              Welcome to tictactoe              ".upcase
    puts"------------------------------------------------"
    print"\n"
    new_game = Game.new
    new_game.create_players
    new_game.instructions
    new_game.players_turn
end

Game.start

end
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview! Could you please indent your code exactly in the way it looks in your ide?

Answer (score 6):

When seeking improvement of a piece of code, the first thing is removing repetition:

```
def mapping(move, symbol)
     case move
        when 0
            if board[0][0]=="X" || @board[0][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[0][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 1
            if board[0][1]=="X" || board[0][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
              board[0][1] = symbol
              process_move(@move)
            end

        when 2
            if board[0][2]=="X" || board[0][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[0][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 3
            if board[1][0]=="X" || board[1][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 4
            if board[1][1]=="X" || board[1][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][1] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 5
            if board[1][2]=="X" || board[1][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[1][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 6
            if board[2][0]=="X" || board[2][0] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][0] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 7
            if board[2][1]=="X" || board[2][1] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][1] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        when 8
            if board[2][2]=="X" || board[2][2] == "O"
               invalid
               make_move
            else
               board[2][2] = symbol
               process_move(@move)
            end

        else 
               invalid
               make_move
    end
end
```

Just the numbers are changing, the actions are the same. We can take advantage of this to shorten this piece of code.

```
def mapping(move, symbol)
     input_to_coords = { 0 : [0, 0], ... 8 : [2, 2] } # Fill in the ellipsis
     x, y = input_to_coords[move]
     if board[x][y]=="X" || board[x][y] == "O"
           invalid
           make_move
        else
           board[x][y] = symbol
           process_move(@move)
        end
  end
```

---

You can also reduce the repetition in `check_win`

```
def check_win?
player = @current
    symbol = @symbol
    if board[0][0] == symbol && 
       board[0][1] == symbol &&
       board[0][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[1][0] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[1][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[2][0] == symbol && 
       board[2][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[0][1] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][1] == symbol
       winner(player)

    elsif
       board[0][2] == symbol && 
       board[1][2] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player) 

    elsif
       board[0][2] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][0] == symbol
       winner(player) 

    elsif
       board[0][0] == symbol && 
       board[1][1] == symbol &&
       board[2][2] == symbol
       winner(player)

    end
     return false
end
```

If at least one (any?) of the triplets are equal to the given symbol, a player wins otherwise false.

```
def check_win?
     triplets =  [ [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2]] ... ]
     triplets.any? {|t| t.all? {|x, y| @board[x][y] == @symbol}} ? winner(player) : false
end
```

Actually I would have chosen a bool as return value, not `winner_player`

**About `move_left?`**

```
 def move_left?
     sum  = @track_move.inject{|r, s| r + s}
     if sum == 36
       return true
     end
end
```

- `sum` is unecessary as an intermediate variable.
- `inject` can be written more shortly.
- `if` is not needed, nor `return` is

:

```
 def move_left?
     @track_move.inject(:+) == 36
 end
```